# Erorr in installing npm install -g firebase-tools

Tags: node.js, npm-install

```
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! path C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\bin\firebase.js
npm ERR! dest C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\firebase
npm ERR! EEXIST: file already exists, cmd shim 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\bin\firebase.js' -> 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\firebase'
npm ERR! File exists: C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\firebase
npm ERR! Remove the existing file and try again, or run npm
npm ERR! with --force to overwrite files recklessly.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-06-09T17_23_51_150Z-debug.log
```

Comment: It tells you what to do: `File exists: C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\firebase Remove the existing file and try again, or run npm with --force to overwrite files recklessly`

Answer (score 1):

to reinstall cleanly, run the following in order.

```
npm uninstall -g firebase-tools

npm cache clean --force

npm install -g firebase-tools
```

Comment: I tried this command in these order you mention it but still get same error and in this time interval i tried reinstall node.js but it not work properly but thanx for your try

Answer (score 0):

You can download the standalone binary(open when done) [download from here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#windows-standalone-binary) it will automatically install CLI
here is the link